# Creating unique ids in a loop

Tags: python, pandas, data-science, data-analysis, data-transform

I've a data set where one of the column is as below. I'd like to create a new column based on the below condition

I know the below code will satisfy the condition
`np.where((df['col']==1),((df['col'] != df1['col'].shift(1)).astype(int).cumsum()),0)`

But if I put the code inside some loop I don't want the `cumsum()` to start from 1 again. It will create duplicates in the end. How can I overcome this??

Is it possible to generate random numbers for that particular condition?? So if it is inside the loop I will still be creating random numbers instead of duplicate ones

```
column_name
1
0
0
1
1
1
1
0
0
1

column_name -- ID
1 -- 1
0 -- 0
0 -- 0
1 -- 2
1 -- 2
1 -- 2
1 -- 2
0 -- 0
0 -- 0
1 -- 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple way to get sequential, int IDs:

```
# setup environment
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(13)

df = pd.DataFrame({'col': [1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1]})

# create masks for use in later updates
msk_one = df['col'] == 1
msk_first = df['col'] != df['col'].shift()

# mark each time a new series of 1s begins with a True
df['ID'] = msk_one & msk_first

# add up the Trues to get sequential ids
df['ID'] = df['ID'].cumsum()

# drop ids on the False rows
df.loc[~msk_one, 'ID'] = 0

print(df)

#    col  ID
# 0    1   1
# 1    0   0
# 2    0   0
# 3    1   2
# 4    1   2
# 5    1   2
# 6    1   2
# 7    0   0
# 8    0   0
# 9    1   3
```

To convert those sequential IDs to random IDs you can do this:

```
# create conversion dict mapping from sequential to random IDS
ids = df['ID'].unique()
# ignore zeros because we want to manually map them to themselves
ids = ids[ids != 0]
random_ids = np.random.choice(ids, len(ids), replace=False)
sequential_to_random = {non_random_id: random_id for non_random_id, random_id in zip(ids, random_ids)}
sequential_to_random[0] = 0

# convert the IDs to random ints
df['ID'] = df['ID'].apply(lambda x: sequential_to_random[x])

print(df)

#    col  ID
# 0    1   2
# 1    0   0
# 2    0   0
# 3    1   1
# 4    1   1
# 5    1   1
# 6    1   1
# 7    0   0
# 8    0   0
# 9    1   3
```

Hope this helps!